# Data entry lookup in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ssms

Microsoft Access allows me to limit the field input values to some pre-determined values, e.g "`Apple`", "`Orange`", "`Tomato`", or even integers like `1`, `2` `215`.

Basically it transforms the table cell from a TextBox into a ComboBox and allows the user to select valid values from the ComboBox.

How can I do this in SQL Server Management Studio (2008 R2 Express)? I enter data by clicking on the table and clicking on "Edit Top 200 Rows".

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

The easiest check for me so far:

In Object Explorer, expand the table, right-click on 'Constraints', click on 'New Constraint...', rename the constraint if desired, type in the expression:

```
([name]='Orange' OR [name]='Apple' OR [name]='Tomato')
```

where "name" is the name of the column, and "Orange", "Apple" and "Tomato" are valid values. You have to use single quotes, I think.

Click 'Close', File | Save All

If there are any conflicts with the new constraint, you will have to work them out before it will let you save.

Now, I want a **COMBO BOX**!   ;)

One annoying result of entering the wrong data and having it fail the check, is that the Primary Key gets incremented anyway and you have gaps in numbers.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.  If you want to restrict the data in a column to some set of values, you can use a foreign key constraint to a table with those values.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, a column should only contain certain values. So I need to set all these values as primary keys in another table then and set up a relationship? Access allowed me to just type them in in the column properties without having to create an extra table. And would this provide a combo box?

Comment: Ok, so I tested it, I think, and when I try to enter a value that is not defined in another table, it throws an error, and I have to correct it. But no joy on getting a nice lookup combo box to select values from.

Comment: You aren't going to get a comboBox.  SSMS isn't Access, and shouldn't be used as a data entry application.

Comment: I see. That answers my question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `check` constraint in SQL Server:

```
alter table t
    add constraint CHK_column_values check (column in ('value1', 'value2'));
```

If you attempt to assign a value where the expression `column in ('value1', 'value2')` does not evaluate to true, then the `insert`/`update` fails.

The expression cannot contain references to other tables.  However, it can contain a user defined function, which could, in turn, check another table.

EDIT:

I originally left the `check` out of the above expression.  The form for your table and values:

```
alter table <your table name here>
    add constraint CHK_column_values check ([name] in ('Apple', 'Orange', 'Tomato'));
```

This is what SSMS studio is doing when you use the menu options.

Comment: Hmm, I am new to SQL. What exactly is `column in ('value1', 'value2')`? And where do I put this script? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to have a ComboBox with valid values?

Comment: @coding4fun . . . This is a SQL solution that is done in the database.  No doubt there is also a way to do the check in a combobox, but that has nothing to do with the SQL tags you put on the question.

Comment: I can't get this syntax to work in Management Studio. It says incorrect syntax. I changed `t` and `column` to my table and column names.

Answer (score 1):

A check constraint in the table definition will limit the values allowed.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190377.aspx

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,name VARCHAR(50)
    CONSTRAINT CHK_name
    CHECK (name = 'Orange' OR name = 'Apple' OR name = 'Tomato')
)

INSERT INTO #temp(name)
VALUES
('Orange')
,('Pink')


Select  *
From    #temp
```